# Understanding Java Converter interface

Tags: java, interface

I need to add the interface called `Converter<Destination, Source>` to provide conversion facilities. I'd write it as follows:

```
public interface Converter<Destination, Source>{
    public Destrination convert(Source o);
}
```

I'm using thrid-party libraries which always have converter interfaces satisfied my needs more-or-less. Should I consider to use them instead of adding the new interface? I'd say no, it would be better off creating a new interface because otherwise we would couple our code to the library which interface we use.

So, what would be the right choice?

Comment: Is this necessarily different from [`java.util.functional.Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) ?

Comment: @khelwood I'm in Java 7. I'm sorry, I forgot to add this importand detail.

Comment: @khelwood No, the interface completely satisfies my needs.

Comment: @St.Antario, do you have Guava in you classpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have Guava in your classpath, there's no need to introduce a brand new interface that does the same as Guava's [`Function`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html), which is defined as:

```
public interface Function<F,T> {
    public T apply(F input);
}
```

Comment: It's even better than Java8's one. It's less verbose, thank you.